# NativeScript "File Not Found With angled Include; use 'quote' instead"

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to add the [VKVideoPlayer](https://github.com/viki-org/) CocoaPod to a NativeScript app, but the build fails with `'DDLog.h' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead`.

This include is in a library (VKFoundation) that is referenced by the VKVideoPlayer. This [VKFoundation.h](https://github.com/viki-org/VKFoundation/blob/master/Classes/ios/VKFoundation.h) file in turn references the `DDLog.h` (from CocoaLumberjack) and `DTCoreText.h` (from DTCoreText).

All of these libraries are pulled in by the VKVideoPlayer Pod.

Here is the relevant error from the command line...

```
/Users/burkeholland/dev/burkeholland/nativescript-video-player/demo/platforms/ios/Pods/VKFoundation/Classes/ios/VKFoundation.h:6:9: error: 
      'DDLog.h' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead
#import <DDLog.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~
        "DDLog.h"
/Users/burkeholland/dev/burkeholland/nativescript-video-player/demo/platforms/ios/Pods/VKFoundation/Classes/ios/VKFoundation.h:7:9: error: 
      'DTCoreText.h' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead
#import <DTCoreText.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        "DTCoreText.h"
2 errors generated.
```

The error can be reproduced from this [GitHub project](https://github.com/burkeholland/nativescript-video-player).

Answer (score 0):

The error itself indicates that one of the referenced headers (DDLog.h) is referenced with `<`, but the compiler cannot find it. So it suggests you to try using `"` quotes instead of angles (`<`). This is a common error raised by XCode when it's unable to find referenced header.
As per your problem, I believe the problem is with VKFoundation Cocoapod, which is a dependency of VKVideoPlayer Pod. Here's a related issue:
https://github.com/viki-org/VKFoundation/issues/5

You can try using the suggested Podfile and see if it works on your side.

Comment: This kind of resolves the issue, but produces a separate error consisting of `include of non-modular header inside framework module 'Reachability.Reachability'`. This appears to be resolved by setting `['CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES'] = 'YES'  ` in the Podfile, but that brings back the `file not found with <angled> include error`. Kind of a circle of insanity. I've updated the Github project with my latest Podfile.